# A tool to test app in different browser version

Tags: java, open-source

Our app supports different browser version from IE to Firefox to Chrome.

Now, some issues are encountered in different browsers and I am having a hard time installing all versions in my computer.

I am not familiar with this, but is there such a tool that I could used where I could configure it to act as if it is FF4, FF5 et al... IE7 to IE 8 et al.. Chrome versions et. al.

I was looking on just switching it to different version to test my app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a virtual machine(or several) could be useful here.

Comment: This is one option also but doing so needs a virtual machine for setup..

Answer (score 0):

The best tool for that would be [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).

Comment: Selenium can't emulate a browser, it can just run tests *against* a specified browser.

Comment: The browser does not have to be on the same machine.

Comment: ahh yes.. we used selenium to do the UI testing.. but I am just wondering if there exist a tool that we can just configure for it to function like different browsers...

Comment: not in that exact sense. there is a phantomJS that is a WebKit only browser emulator tool. But no IE emulators afaik.

Comment: @Dmitry: I didn't say it did.  My point is that this doesn't help you manage a big set of different versioned browsers, it just helps you automate stuff against browsers.

Comment: There is also HTMLUnit but my experience is that both tools don't even come close to mimicking the quirks that you find in the real browser.  Always test against real browsers regularly (Selenium is a great choice to automate this!)

Comment: Right, I agree. To manage a "fleet" of browsers you would need several machines probably. Firefox has "profiles" that Selenium knows about. Other browsers - I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

Safari has an option in the *Developer* menu that allows you to choose which user agent to emulate.

The list of options is pretty long...